# Segmentation fault (core dumped) Redirecting input

Tags: c++, pipe, dup2

For my program, I have done funcs

```
void clear_forward() {
    if (saved_stdout) {
        dup2(saved_stdout, 1);
        if (close(saved_stdout))
            saved_stdout = 0;
    }
    if (saved_stdin) {
        dup2(saved_stdin, 0);
        if (close(saved_stdin))
            saved_stdin = 0;
    }
    if (saved_stderr) {
        dup2(saved_stderr, 2);
        if (close(saved_stderr))
            saved_stderr = 0;
    }
}
```

and

```
void forward() {
    int fd_out, fd_in, fd_err;
    if (!saved_stdout) {
        saved_stdout = dup(1);
    }
    if (!saved_stdin) {
        saved_stdout = dup(0);
    }
    if (!saved_stderr) {
        saved_stderr = dup(2);
    }
    if (strcmp(out_file.c_str(), "") != 0) {
        if ((saved_stdout < 0)) {
            fprintf(stderr, "Can't dup(2) - (%s)\n", strerror(errno));
            exit(1);
        }
        if ((fd_out = open(out_file.c_str(), O_RDWR | O_TRUNC | O_CREAT, S_IRUSR | S_IWUSR)) < 0) {
            fprintf(stderr, "Can't open(2) - (%s)\n", strerror(errno));
            exit(1);
        }
        if (dup2(fd_out, 1) < 0) // redirect output to the file
        {
            fprintf(stderr, "Can't dup2(2) - (%s)\n", strerror(errno));
            exit(1);
        }
        close(fd_out);  // Descriptor no longer needed
    }

    if (strcmp(inp_file.c_str(), "") != 0) {
        if ((saved_stdout < 0)) {
            fprintf(stderr, "Can't dup(2) - (%s)\n", strerror(errno));
            exit(1);
        }
        if ((fd_in = open(inp_file.c_str(), O_RDWR | O_TRUNC | O_CREAT, S_IRUSR | S_IWUSR)) < 0) {
            fprintf(stderr, "Can't open(2) - (%s)\n", strerror(errno));
            exit(1);
        }
        if (dup2(fd_in, 0) < 0) // redirect input from file
        {
            fprintf(stderr, "Can't dup2(2) - (%s)\n", strerror(errno));
            exit(1);
        }
        close(fd_in);  // Descriptor no longer needed

    }
    if (strcmp(err_file.c_str(), "") != 0) {
        if (saved_stderr < 0) {
            fprintf(stderr, "Can't dup(2) - (%s)\n", strerror(errno));
            exit(1);
        }
        if ((fd_err = open(err_file.c_str(), O_RDWR | O_TRUNC | O_CREAT, S_IRUSR | S_IWUSR)) < 0) {
            fprintf(stderr, "Can't open(2) - (%s)\n", strerror(errno));
            exit(1);
        }

        if (dup2(fd_err, 2) < 0) // redirect input from file
        {
            fprintf(stderr, "Can't dup2(2) - (%s)\n", strerror(errno));
            exit(1);
        }
        close(fd_err);  // Descriptor no longer needed
    }
}
```

So after I run I want the redirecting to work. But works only redirection to file, but not getting input from file. What can be the problem?:

```
int run(string arguments){
    clear_forward();
    vector<string> parsed_args = parse_args(std::move(arguments));
    if (parsed_args.size()==2 && !strcmp(parsed_args[0].c_str(), ".")) {
        string line;
        std::ifstream infile(parsed_args[1]);
        while (std::getline(infile, line)) {
            if (! line.empty()) {
                run(line, fd);
            } else { continue; }
            add_history(line.c_str());
        }
    }
    if(parsed_args.empty()){
        return 0;
    }

    forward();
    if(is_internal(parsed_args)){
        return run_internal(parsed_args);

    } else
        return execute(parsed_args);
}
```

How should i perform this? Execute is just fork exec from parsed args, how should I add the input from file to that? manually read from STDIN if there is an input file??

Comment: Step through it with a debugger. Find the exact line(s) of code where it goes wrong. Post the relevant lines of code. _Then we'll talk._

Answer (score 0):

In your `forward()` function:

```
if (!saved_stdin) {
    saved_stdout = dup(0);
}
```

You probably *don't* want to be checking `saved_stdin` and then duplicating `stdin` to ***`saved_stdout`.***

What you probably meant was:

```
if (!saved_stdin) {
    saved_stdin = dup(0);
}
```